# Is the hypergeometric function $_2F_1\left[\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2};n+1;z\right]$ expressible in terms of more elementary functions?

Tags: probability-theory, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is this special case of hypergeometric function expressible in terms of more elementary functions :

> $$_2F_1\left[\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2};n+1;z\right]$$

It will also be helpful for me to know, if this function appears in any well studied discrete probability functions.

$\textbf{Note :}$ $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{}^{+}$ and $z \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq z \leq 1$.

Comment: I guess $n$ is an integer? Positive?

Comment: @Fabian Yes, I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple relates this to the associated Legendre polynomials/functions:
$$_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2};n+1;z\right) = {z}^{-n/2}P^{-n}_{-1/2}\left(-{\frac {z+1}{z-1}}\right) \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\sqrt{1-z}}$$

See also [Abramowitz/Stegun 15.4.15](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_562.htm) with $a=1/2, b=n+1/2$

Comment: Thank you. Mathematica was not able to simplify. Does this hold for complex $z$.

Comment: Yes, for complex $z$ (with some restrictions) this is 15.4.14 on the same A/S page.

Comment: The first few of these (and I assume all of them) have the form $$\frac{A(z)}{\pi}\;K(\sqrt{z})+\frac{B(z)}{\pi}\;F(\sqrt{z})$$where $A(z), B(z)$ are rational functions and $F,K$ are the complete elliptic integrals.  (I used Maple, perhaps as usual the $\sqrt{z}$ would be $z$ in Mathematica notation.)